# How to insert data into mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a record to the mongodb blogdb hosted at port 27017 using nodeJS.

I keep getting the error in the image. The error I'm getting is "**localhost:27017 socket closed**"

The record I am trying to enter is

```
var post1 = {
    title:"Flight 2012",
    by:"posiden",
    tags:["planes","movies","pilot"],
    likes:86,
};
```

Here is my db.js file which I have executed as node db.js

```
[![//require mongodb native drivers
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
//getting the mongo client interface to connect witha  mongodb server
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
//connection url of the database
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/blogdb';
//use the connect method to conenct to the server
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){

    if(err){
        console.log("Unabel to connect to mongo server ERROR : " ,err);
    }else {
        console.log("Connection sucesful to ", url);

        var collection = db.collection('posts');
        var post1 = {
            title: "Flight 2012",
            by: "posiden",
            tags: \["planes", "movies", "pilot"\],
            likes: 86,
        };
        collection.insert(\[post1\], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR ", err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("SUCCESS INSERTED in to users collection _is are ", result.length, result)
            }
        });

    }]
```

[image]

Comment: What the "escape" slashing here? If you take all the `\\`` out then everything is okay. And of course the `[1][1]` on the end. Which what is that about?

Comment: Can you explain your last line `][1]][1]` and the `\[post1\]`?

Comment: first, can you please check if mongo is running using command "mongod" ?

Comment: The socket closed error indicates the database cannot be reached. Can you verify that the database is running and if it is, are you on a Windows based machine? You could have an issue with Mongo becoming locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your JSON is incorrect. It should not have comma(',') after last element in your JSON(which in your case is "likes:86"). Below is correct JSON:

```
var post1 = {
    title:"Flight 2012",
    by:"posiden",
    tags:["planes","movies","pilot"],
    likes:86
};
```

Please try after this. Please report in case you still get the issue.